# How to use a Selectbox as Navigation in Jekyll?

Tags: select, navigation, jekyll

In my Jekyll-Page I want to use a Select for the main navigation.

This is my Code:

```
<select id="navigation">
   <option value="/" selected>start</option>
   <option value="/about">about</option>
   <option value="/blog">blog</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementById("navigation").onchange = function() {
      var selectedOption = this.value;
      window.location.href = "http://127.0.0.1:4000/" + selectedOption;
   }
</script>
```

I want to set the current page automaticly as selected. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [page.url](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/#page-variables) variable as such:

```
<select id="navigation">
   <option value="/" {% if page.url == '/' %}selected{% endif %}>start</option>
   <option value="/about" {% if page.url == '/about' %}selected{% endif %}>about</option>
   <option value="/blog" {% if page.url == '/blog' %}selected{% endif %}>blog</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

The nicest way to do it, is like this (example from [JekyllCodex.org](http://JekyllCodex.org)):

```
{% assign url_parts = page.url | split: '/' %}
<select>
<option {% if '' == url_parts[1] %}selected{% endif %}>start</option>
<option {% if 'about' == url_parts[1] %}selected{% endif %}>about</option>
<option {% if 'blog' == url_parts[1] %}selected{% endif %}>blog</option>
</select>
```